# OOP(Object Oriented Programming)

Tags: oop

This is not a specific question about a certain piece of code and apologies if my current question is not valid on StackOverflow. With Such a big Community I am just curious to find a common approach for best practices.

It's not that I Don't know how to code the OOP way, but while my code keeps growing I am losing track and my code actually bluntly stated gets "ugly". What happens is that it takes a lot of time to rewrite my code to finally have it correct again.

Don't get me wrong. I really take time and dedication to adapt my code the best way I can. I rewrite parts that can be rewritten etc. Actually I want to avoid to rewrite and I know it takes alot of practice. Any Guidelines/Tips regarding taking on a project is highly appreciated.

I Have written Code already in OOP way, but it's small code/project based and now when I am starting to take on bigger projects I lose track.

My question is simply: Am I the only one that has this? And how to keep my coding neat all the way to the end?

Thanks in advance for any tips regarding this situation. I just want to write better and cleaner code.

Comment: Try to give more details about your code, the programming language that you are using, post some code that you are trying to refactor, etc.

Comment: Try learning software design patterns (some are language specific) for writing clean and maintainable code.

Comment: Hi, just use SCA -> static code analysis tools for scanning your code, there are a lot of oss solutions and also a lot of commercial software. May be this helps (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis). Within these tools are rules defined to find code smells e.g. with code metrics.

Comment: This is a very broad question but I can assure you this is practically "normal" in any large project.

Comment: You've got some downvotes, but don't be frustrated about this. If you don't get good answer here, try the [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) community - it suits better for such questions.

Comment: @haihui, I wrote this while traveling. Just chain of thought. I will try in the future to give code examples when I need a question answered.

Comment: @AshishKamat, next step! thank you.

Comment: @BorisSerebrov heey, thank you for the advice. I really am not frustrated about downvotes. I would love the downvoters to only explain theirselfs what lead them to downvote me :). I will join that community certainly !

Comment: @Amit, I can understand that, but I would like to avoid it as much as possible =).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In practice, you often might need to update your existing code to meet the new requirements. But if this is something you are doing on regular basis, then it is possible that your development process is not good enough.

You may lack a beforehand thinking and planning process.
What do you do when you have a new development task? Do you just go on and write some code?

I use the process like this:

1) **User story**.
Describe a user story, it often comes from the customer or users. This can be something like "I want to have a new beautiful chart of the recent data on the dashboard".

2) **Requirements specification**. Start asking questions and add details. You may need to create a separate document just to describe all the details - what data exactly should be shown, should it be line or bar or other kind of chart, where exactly should the chart be placed, etc, etc...

Result - a detailed requirements specification. It should be clear enough so you can give it to other developer, who should be able to continue with following steps without asking the questions.

Check also this article [10 Typical Mistakes in Specs](http://www.yegor256.com/2015/11/10/ten-mistakes-in-specs.html).

3) **Implementation details**. Think how to implement the requirements, describe the classes structure and objects interaction, think on extensibility and flexibility, plan the unit tests for your code.

The basic idea is that you start writing and re-writing your code even before you actually write the real code.
Imagine how your classes / objects will be used, try to write some tests before actually writing the code.

Here is where [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)), [design patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612) and [UML diagrams](http://www.holub.com/goodies/uml/) can be useful to design your code in a good way.

4) **Estimation**. If you was good at point (3), it will be trivial to split your implantation into small steps and estimate how much time you will need for every step, like:

- Database migration - add new tables - 1h
- Implement ClassA, ClassB, ClassC - 1h
- Implement ClassD, with a special calculation algorithm - 4h
- Unit tests - 2h
- Testing, fixing bugs found - 20% of the above

I usually use this scheme of estimation (along with 20% for unexpected things) and it is possible to get very accurate estimations. Like for a 40 hour task it can be 1-2 hours error, it should never be something like 50% error.

5) **Implementation**. Here you just go on and do the task.
Everything is planned, everything is absolutely clear.
No thinking on design and strategy, only local decisions (like do I use `for` or `while` loop here?).

This way you minimize the amount of "surprises" during the implementation and reduce the need in re-writing the code later.

Comment: Thank you, very detailed and guidelines i can use!

Answer (score 1):

Always keep SOLID in mind. That will help you to stay on the right track. Here is a good start http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod

Comment: Thank you ! I will certainly look into this. Looks very indepth .